# cursor pointer on marker in openstreetmaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, openstreetmap

I have this code with openstreetmaps (is a circle, then I have more markers named marker1, marker2, marker3 and so on), but property **curosor: pointer** doesn't work (I tried with a lot of browsers).

Also tried with css:

```
.ol-marker .ol-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The same, doesn't work.

```
    // Create a marker feature 1    
    var marker1 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([14.3619382, 46.0649361])),
        name: 'some text',
        description: 'other some text'
    });

    // Create a marker style 1  
    var markerStyle1 = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: '/assets/images/ico.png',
        scale: 1            }),
        cursor: 'pointer'
    });
            
    // Set style to marker feature 1    
    marker1.setStyle(markerStyle1);

    // Add the marker feature 1 to the vector source
    vectorSource.addFeature(marker1);
```

Comment: Maybe `curosor: pointer` doesn't work because it should be `cursor: pointer`? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

@mkrieger1 sure, it was typing error in description, but if you see the code it's correct
doesn't work means that cursor also on marker is standard type, not pointer. No error in console, I'm using this version cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.2.2/dist/ol.js